# Dgrid - how to start row rendering at a specific index

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I'm using Dgrid with an Observable JsonRest store. The JsonRest store is queried for 50 rows at a time. Now I have a function where the user can 'quicksearch' the data and the search is processed on the serverside. This works, and in this case the server returns for example "Content-Range: 210-260/1500". It returns 50 rows of data but Dgrid renders the full grid at the beginning, so the user can't scroll 'up' for previous entries.

How can I make Dgrid behave like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I'm completely grasping your problem, but if I am, it may require some thinking outside the box or compromising to get what you want.  I assume your UI is basically jumping to the first match rather than simply filtering the grid to only show matches.

If your UI is such that the grid is always present and the search is basically intended to scroll the grid, you can use `grid.scrollTo({ y: valueInPixels })` to scroll the grid.  While this accepts a pixel value (not rows), if your rows are consistent height, you can multiply by `grid.rowHeight` (which is a property set by `OnDemandList`) to get the correct offset.

Another option, though probably not what you want, would be to use the [Pagination extension](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.16/doc/components/extensions/Pagination.md) and navigate to a specific page.

Of course, if you would rather actually filter the grid to only display matching items, that's possible too (assuming your server behaves as `dojo/store/JsonRest` expects, anyway).  The [Using Grids and Stores tutorial](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/) has an example towards the end.

Comment: I've tried the 'scrollTo' option but it didn't really work, probably because our rowheight is not consistent. I will implement the 'filter' option which is a better option for our UI. Thanks.